# What's going on with the moderator tools?

Tags: support, 10k-tools

A couple of days ago I was trying to find the "Review" page through the moderators tools link by the badges indicators.

I couldn't find it for the life of me, but after a couple of hours the issue was solved and all was well.

*Now* I can't find the moderator tools. Only the review page... What's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tools and Review were merged.

Where it says

`Tools | Review`

Click one or the other to switch.